# Can I fix my GPU clock rate to ensure consistent profiling results?

Tags: cuda, profiling, benchmarking, clock

I want to do some comparative profiling of a couple of CUDA kernels. However, one of them runs within a program which loads the GPU with more work, while the other is only running in a test harness.

For some GPUs, these circumstances mean the clock rates change (perhaps more than one kind of clock rate, because there are several). This effect is particularly severe in devices like Tesla T4's (which aren't actively cooled).

Is it possible to prevent clock rates from changing due to load (or thermal conditions)?

I've looked into doing this the `nvidia-smi` utility, which has a sub-command named `clocks` - but all that does is the following:

```
clocks -- Control and query clock information.

Usage: nvidia-smi clocks [options]
options include:
   [-i | --id]: Enumeration index, PCI bus ID or UUID. Provide comma
                 separated values for more than one device
   [ | --sync-boost-list]: List all synchronous boost groups
   [ | --sync-boost-add]: Add a synchronous boost group

   [ | --sync-boost-remove]: Remove a synchronous boost group. Provide the group id
                 returned from --sync-boost-list
```

... and it doesn't look like that's what I need. Of course, non-`nvidia-smi`-based solutions are welcome.

Notes:

- I'm particularly interested in fixing clock rates for Quadro and Tesla cards, in case that matters.
- I can be root if necessary.
- Using CUDA 10.2 with its bundled driver. If absolutely necessary, I might be able to switch to a new version.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TL;DR

1. first, **set persistence mode** e.g. `nvidia-smi -i 0 -pm 1` (sets persistence mode for the GPU index 0)
2. use a `nvidia-smi` command like `-ac` or `-lgc` (application clocks, lock gpu clock)
3. there is `nvidia-smi` command line help for all of this `nvidia-smi --help`
4. this functionality may not work on your GPU.  Install the latest driver, and also some of this functionality is simply not available on certain products
5. these settings often require root privilege, or admin privilege on windows
6. any of this description is subject to change.  With some care, the command-line help for the version you are using should be instructive

LONGER:

I'm using driver 455.23.05 for this description.  Some features (e.g. `-lgc`) may not be available in older drivers.  Setting persistence mode may be necessary for some of these features, and will also help to reduce variability on application start-up.  *This is not intended to be an exhaustive description of the* `nvidia-smi` *tool*.

SETTING APPLICATION CLOCKS:

The application clocks feature should generally be useful for the testing described.  It will not force the GPU clocks to remain at the specified setting when there is no application running (AFAIK), but the clocks should attain those values "as soon as" the application starts running.  It allows you to specify both gpu clock (i.e. core clock) as well as memory clock.  Let's start by excerpting the command line help text for some of the important switches:

```
-ac   --applications-clocks= Specifies <memory,graphics> clocks as a
                                pair (e.g. 2000,800) that defines GPU's
                               speed in MHz while running applications on a GPU.
-rac  --reset-applications-clocks
                           Resets the applications clocks to the default values.
-acp  --applications-clocks-permission=
                            Toggles permission requirements for -ac and -rac commands:
                            0/UNRESTRICTED, 1/RESTRICTED
```

To get started setting application clocks, you may need to use `sudo` or similar on linux for some or all of these commands.  Also note above the requirement for elevated privilege can be turned on/off.  Also important is that you cannot pick any values you like for `<memory,graphics>` settings pair.  You must specify a pair, and furthermore the pair can only come from a list of permissible options.  Other choices will result in unspecified behavior.  These choices can be determined from the `--query-supported-clocks` switch (use `--help-query-supported-clocks` to get command-line help on that switch) to `nvidia-smi` which itself requires some formatting.  For example, the following command will give an exhaustive list of the valid pairs that can be passed to the `-ac` command:

```
nvidia-smi -i 0 --query-supported-clocks=mem,gr --format=csv
```

Once you have that list of valid pairs, you can specify one of those pairs to the application clocks command:

```
nvidia-smi -i 0 -ac 877,1215
```

(The above command, if run with root or enabled via `-acp` would set the memory clock to 877MHz and the core clock to 1215MHz on my Tesla V100, for example.  Note the `-i` switch to select the GPU to target with this command.  The 877,1215 pair *may not be valid on your GPU*.  Also note that the `-acp` feature is removed from drivers 465.xx and newer.)

When you are done with whatever you are doing, you may wish to reset the application clock behavior to the default behavior (GPU selects clock freqs according to its own heuristics) using `-rac`.

Also, a number of the pairs offered may involve "boosting" behavior.  **The GPU is not guaranteed to maintain all clocks exactly as you specify**, if a throttling event occurs.  Typical throttling events are:

1. GPU is consuming too much electrical power
2. GPU temperature is too high

The existence of an actual throttling event can be discovered using the "full" output from nvidia-smi (`nvidia-smi -a`), look for "clocks throttle reasons".  Other useful information is available in this output such as the default application clocks.  When `N/A` appears in your output, it means that your GPU does not support this feature.  There is a great variety of supported features across various GPU families, I won't be able to respond to questions about this.

In the absence of a  throttling event, and assuming your GPU supports the feature, I would expect application clocks to remain in effect throughout your application runtime.  Note that if this command is specified while an application is currently running, the change in clocks *may* not take effect until the GPU becomes idle.  You may wish to monitor GPU clocks in this case (again, using `nvidia-smi`).  Therefore I would generally recommend using these commands when the GPU is idle.  Then begin your work on the GPU after that.

LOCK GPU (CORE) CLOCK:

In many cases, the gpu core clock (core, gpu, graphics are all synonyms in this context) exhibits the most variability (for example the application clocks offered on my Tesla V100 only include a value of 877MHz for memory clock; no other choices are possible).  There is a separate switch that can be used to "lock" the GPU core clock to a range of values.

```
-lgc  --lock-gpu-clocks=    Specifies <minGpuClock,maxGpuClock> clocks as a
                                pair (e.g. 1500,1500) that defines the range
                                of desired locked GPU clock speed in MHz.
                                Setting this will supercede application clocks
                                and take effect regardless if an app is running.
                                Input can also be a singular desired clock value
                                (e.g. <GpuClockValue>).
-rgc  --reset-gpu-clocks
                            Resets the Gpu clocks to the default values.
```

This range is specified using a lower and upper endpoint for the range.  If you wish to select a specific value only, you can specify the lower and upper endpoints both to be that value.  As far as I know the range endpoints are inclusive.

For example, the following command:

```
nvidia-smi -i 0 -lgc 1215,1215
```

will "lock" the GPU core clock to 1215 MHz on my Tesla V100 GPU.  As far as I know, this effect takes place immediately, even if an application is running.  Most other caveats I can think of should be similar for application clocks:

- choose a valid GPU core clock, as output from the `--query-supported-clocks` command
- GPU is not guaranteed to maintain the request in the event of throttling
- elevated privilege is required
- reset the behavior with `-rgc`

As indicated in the help, this switch "overrides" previous application clocks settings with respect to core clock. Also, note that many switches come in 2 flavors, a "long" form and a "short" form.  Where additional switch parameters are required, the long form often requires an `=` separator, the short form often requires a space separator:

```
 nvidia-smi -i 0 -lgc 1215,1215
```

or

```
 nvidia-smi -i 0 -lock-gpu-clocks=1215,1215
```

you generally cannot intermix this formatting:

```
 nvidia-smi -i 0 -lgc=1215,1215
```

will probably report an error.

A FINAL NOTE:

> This effect is particularly severe in devices like Tesla T4's (which aren't actively cooled).

In my experience with T4, a possible observation is **throttling**.  The T4 GPU is one of the lowest power datacenter-grade GPUs, and its certainly possible for the GPU compute demands to exceed what the power limits (70W) can support.  In this case, the GPU clocks will throttle, and none of the above commands will allow you to override this behavior.  By design, you cannot force the GPU to operate at elevated clocks when the GPU is trying to protect itself, or protect the system it is running in.

Also, the fact that a T4 is not actively cooled really should not matter.  The only approved/supported usage setting for a T4 is in [a server that is designed to handle the T4](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/resources/vgpu-certified-servers/). (A similar statement is true for any NVIDIA Datacenter GPU). Such servers monitor the T4 GPU temperature and provide server-delivered forced flow-through cooling to the GPU.  This is by design.  The server is responsible for keeping the GPU in a proper temperature operating range.  If the server is not doing that, you should address that with your server vendor.  If you are operating the T4 GPU in a non-approved setting (such as a non-qualified server, or a desktop/workstation) then I would generally expect the experience with that device to be dismal.

MORE RECENTLY: NVIDIA has published [this blog](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/advanced-api-performance-setstablepowerstate/) which covers many of the same topics.  If there are discrepancies between what I have stated above, and the blog, the blog should be considered the best source.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this long tract. I will likely try this out this coming week. I'll just note that I don't intend to set the clocks particularly high, I just want to set them to the same thing. About your note regarding the T4: You're absolutely right. But I can't conduct my experiments on such a specialty server for, well, reasons. I'm being careful not to let the T4 heat up too much so my experiments are spaced out in time.

Comment: @einpoklum In my experience with single-slot Quadro designs that are similar in specs to the T4, with sufficient cooling there is often *power-based throttling*, because a PCIe slot can deliver only 75W and NVIDIA's power management ensures that is strictly enforced, keeping power consumption under continuous heavy load more around 65W.